# Install a Gnome Shell extension

Tags: gnome, shell, extensions

I'd like to install a Gnome Shell extension for audio settings: [sound-output-device-chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser)

I've checked the Gnome version:

```
cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml
```

and downloaded the extension for Gnome 3.18, [version 16](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/sound-output-device-chooser%40kgshank.net.v16.shell-extension.zip):

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net.v16.shell-extension
unzip ~/Downloads/sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net.v16.shell-extension.zip -d ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net.v16.shell-extension
```

but I can't see any way to enable it (even in `gnome-tweak-tool`)

I tried to apply it manually, but after restart I couldn't log in:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions['sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net.v16.shell-extension']
```

Answer (score 5):

This is likely due to the fact that elementary is running the Pantheon desktop not Gnome Shell. While Pantheon is built upon GTK3, it is not a Gnome Shell desktop. Therefore many things that work in Gnome Shell will not work in Pantheon.